# spring 3 sub-bean validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I try to validate via `org.springframework.validation.Validator`.

My Problem: I have the a form-bean which has data beans.

```
PlayerRegistrationDataBean
-> has: PersonBean
```

So how do I have to validate the `PersonBean` if I do not want to implement the validation everywhere I use `PersonBeans` as "sub-beans"?

Comment: org.springframework.validation.Validator is an interface of which there are many implementations that work in very different ways.  You need to help us out a little bit more with what you're actually using as the validation framework.  jsr303 with Hibernate Validator?

Comment: I am self-implementing the validator.
Where do I find the already available implementations and where do I find the documentation?
You probably noticed that I am new to spring... :-)

Comment: Currently I am Implementing one validator for the form-bean and other validators for the sub-beans used in the form-bean.
The right path to the element do validate is reached by forwarding the prefix of the sub-bean to the sub-bean validator from the form-bean validator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure am I getting what you're asking about, but won't annotating the PersonBean's properties with proper annotations and then the PersonBean itself with @Valid do the trick?

Comment: That is one way I could go, but wanted to be able to use different validations on the same class.
So I have choosen the spring-way.